# How to check for authenticated() or hasIpAddress for the same antMatcher()?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to configure Sprint Security to check if the user is authenticated **or** if the request comes from a specific IP subnet.

I wrote the following code that is not working as expected:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.valueOf("POST"), "/api/something").authenticated();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.valueOf("POST"), "/api/something").hasIpAddress("172.17.0.0/24");
  }
```

Each configuration works individually, but I don't know how to put them together using an **OR** operator.

The problem is that the second configuration overrides the first one.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html) with SpEL

```java
http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.valueOf("POST"), "/api/something")
                .access("hasIpAddress('172.17.0.0/24') or isAuthenticated()")
```